# jQuery Math Equation

Tags: jquery, math

I'm having a little trouble with this simple equation, any help is greatly appreciated.

My desired result is: 
226 - Input value * .5

I can't figure out how/where to add 226 before the input value, this is what I'm working with:

HTML

```
  <form id='myform'>
      <input value=" "/><br>
      <a href="#" class='THR'>click to calculate THR</a><br><br>
  </form>
```

CODE

```
 $('a.THR').click(function() {
    $('#myform :text').each(function() {
     this.value *= .5;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a.THR').click(function() {
    $('#myform :text').each(function() {
     var value = parseFloat(this.value);
      this.value = 226 - value * 0.5;
    });
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to add another equestion to this, how can I adjust it? 
for example:

    Input Value = " "

    *.5 =         " "  (result #1)

  
    Input Value = " "  *.9 =         " "  (result #2)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.THR').click(function() {
     $('#myform :text').each(function() {
        $(this).val(226 - ($(this).val() * 0.5));
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me,  226 - [input value] * .5.  Subtracts the value from 226 and then divides by 2.  Correct?

```
$(function() {

    $('a.THR').click(function() {
        $('#myform :text').each(function() {
            this.value = (226 - this.value) * .5;
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I think your text description is wrong. I would expect it to divide vlaue by 2 before subtracting it from 226. Your description implies (226-value)/2...

Comment: Hey Chris, sounds strange  but that's the required equation

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the feedback Chris.  I've changed the equation to match what Sean is asking for.